# Convergence of an 'Eisenstein' double sum

Tags: real-analysis, complex-analysis, modular-forms

I'm currently studying the Eisenstein Series and would like to show that said series is holomorphic. In doing so, I want to show that
$$\sum_{(n,m) \in \mathbb{Z}^2} \frac{1}{|m^2 + n^2 - mn|^k} = \sum_{(n,m) \in \mathbb{Z}^2} \frac{1}{|m \gamma - n|^k},$$

converges for $k \ge 3$ and where $\gamma = e^{2\pi i/3}.$ I've tried bounding this by numerous things but I'm not getting anywhere.

Any help showing that this converges would be greatly appreciated - thanks!

Comment: Perhaps think about a more-than-one-dimensional "integral test"... some technicalities, indeed, but don't let those inhibit your heuristic... :)

Comment: $\displaystyle\sum_{(m,n) \ne (0,0)} |m\tau+n|^{-a} $ converges for $a >2$ since  $\int_1^\infty \int_0^\infty (x |\tau|+y)^{-a} dxdy =\frac{1}{a-1}\int_1^\infty (x|\tau|)^{1-a}dx$ converges